# Struct in c# giving warning Field is never assigned to,and will always have its default value0

Tags: c#

I have very simple struct as below:

```
 public struct ShFileInfo
 {
     public int hIcon;
     public int iIcon;
     public int dwAttributes;
 }
```

I have enabled **warning as error**. Now for all three `int` getting error

> Field is never assigned to,and will always have its default value 0

Obviously I will get error if I try to initialize the `int` to `0`. Is there any way to handle this without disabling warning as error.

Comment: Just add a constructor with at least one parameter and initialize them all.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you have? This really shouldn't cause a warning, since all the fields are public.

Comment: @Luaan Yes this is the exact code i have

Comment: Is the struct contained within another class that's marked as `private` or `internal`?

Comment: As soon as you start using the constructor the warning should go away.

Comment: Cover your eyes, kids. It's a mutable struct with exposed fields.

Comment: Ah, you're using this for P/Invokes, aren't you? So you aren't actually ever assigning to those fields in your code.

Comment: Luaan correct @AdrianoRepetti solution works

Comment: put your full code..?is it your full code..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had been receiving the warning when I copy pasted author's code.
[image: Warning received]

You can define a constructor for the Struct like this

```
public struct ShFileInfo
    {
        public int hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public int dwAttributes;

        public ShFileInfo(int x,int y, int z)
        {
            hIcon = x;
            iIcon = y;
            dwAttributes = z;
        }
    }
```

You can also use a constructor with just one parameter and initialize all

```
  public ShFileInfo(int x)
        {
            hIcon = x;
            iIcon = 0;
            dwAttributes = 0;
        }
```

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, so would anyone care to leave a comment stating the reason to down vote before doing that, so that I wouldn't commit the same mistake again

Comment: This doesn't address the problem why author sees this warning message on a first place... I just copy pasted autohrs code to visual studio and i couldn't reproduce this issue. If you answer this question as well i'd change my downvote to upvote.

Comment: @Fabjan Thanks for the info, I dont know what I was doing wrong, but I copy pasted the authors code and I was able to see the same issue, ie 3 warnings saying 'Field is never assigned to,and will always have its default value 0', So i corrected it by adding a constructor

Comment: My little advice is to be careful with unclear questions like this one even though they are simple but your answer most likely will get downvoted by folks here if you'd not provide a complete and exhaustive answer. Ok i upvoted your answer now

Comment: @Fabjan Thanks for the advice I have added a image to show that I am getting the warning that the Author gets.

Comment: Works for me i had missed intialization

Answer (score 8):

If your struct is inside internal class then you get this warrning

```
internal class WrapperClass
{
    public struct ShFileInfo
    {
        public int hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public int dwAttributes;
    }
}
```

when you change internal access to public then warnings gone:

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public struct ShFileInfo
    {
        public int hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public int dwAttributes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using this structure for P/Invoke only, I'd simply disable the warning locally:

```
#pragma warning disable 0649
public struct ShFileInfo
{
    public int hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public int dwAttributes;
}
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

The compiler has no way of knowing that your structure is assigned in the unmanaged code, but since you know, there's little hurt in simply disabling the warning.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, imo.